# How to get output of intermediate Keras layers in batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I am not sure how to get output of an intermediate layer in Keras. I have read the other questions on stackoverflow but they seem to be functions with a single sample as input. I want to get output features(at intermediate layer) in batches as well. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ResNet50(include_top = False, pooling = RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE, weights = resnet_weights_path)) #None
model.add(Dense(784, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation = DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION))
model.layers[0].trainable = True
```

After training the model, in my code I want to get the output after the first dense layer (784 dimensional). Is this the right way to do it?

`pred = model.layers[1].predict_generator(data_generator, steps = len(data_generator), verbose = 1)`

I am new to Keras so I am a little unsure. Do I need to compile the model again after training?

Comment: The same question has been asked many times, please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=keras+intermediate+layer

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have seen them. I am just unsure if I can pass data generator as function argument.

Comment: That seems to be a different question, and pass a generator to which function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you don't need to compile again after training.

Based on your **Sequential** model.

```
Layer 0 :: model.add(ResNet50(include_top = False, pooling = RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE, weights = resnet_weights_path)) #None
Layer 1 :: model.add(Dense(784, activation = 'relu'))
Layer 2 :: model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation = DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION))
```

Accessing the layers, may differ if used **Functional API** approach.

Using **Tensorflow 2.1.0**, you could try this approach when you want to access intermediate outputs.

```
model_dense_784 = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs = model.layers[1].output)

pred_dense_784 = model_dense_784.predict(train_data_gen, steps = 1) # predict_generator is deprecated

print(pred_dense_784.shape) # Use this to check Output Shape
```

It is highly advisable to use the `model.predict()` method, rather than `model.predict_generator()` as it is already **deprecated**.
You could also use `shape()` method to check whether the **output generated** is the **same** as indicated on the `model.summary()`.