# How to get the result of an intermediate layer in keras with Siamese Networks and Functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, siamese-network

I have the following network definition for siamese networks:

```
def build_siamese_model(inputShape, embeddingDim=48):
    # specify the inputs for the feature extractor network
    inputs = Input(inputShape)

    ## first set of CONV => RELU => RESID=> POOL => DROPOUT layers
    first_conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(inputs)
    first_batch_norm1=BatchNormalization()(first_conv1)
    first_act1= LeakyReLU()(first_batch_norm1)

    second_conv1 = Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same")(inputs)
    second_batch_norm1=BatchNormalization()(second_conv1)
    second_act1= LeakyReLU()(second_batch_norm1)

    third_conv1 = Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding="same")(inputs)
    third_batch_norm1=BatchNormalization()(third_conv1)
    third_act1= LeakyReLU()(third_batch_norm1)

    residual_block1= Add()([first_act1, second_act1, third_act1])
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(residual_block1)
    dropout1 = Dropout(0.3)(pool1)

    #receiver Convolutional layer
    receiver1_conv = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(dropout1)
    receiver1_batch_norm=BatchNormalization()(receiver1_conv)
    act_receiver1=LeakyReLU()(receiver1_batch_norm)

    ## second set of CONV => BN=> RELU => RESID=> POOL => DROPOUT layers
    first_conv2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(act_receiver1)
    first_batch_norm2=BatchNormalization()(first_conv2)
    first_act2= LeakyReLU()(first_batch_norm2)

    second_conv2 = Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same")(act_receiver1)
    second_batch_norm2=BatchNormalization()(second_conv2)
    second_act2= LeakyReLU()(second_batch_norm2)

    third_conv2 = Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding="same")(act_receiver1)
    third_batch_norm2=BatchNormalization()(third_conv2)
    third_act2= LeakyReLU()(third_batch_norm2)
    
    residual_block2= Add()([first_act2, second_act2, third_act2])
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(residual_block2)
    dropout2 = Dropout(0.3)(pool2)
    
    #receiver Convolutional layer
    receiver2_conv = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(dropout2)
    receiver2_batch_norm=BatchNormalization()(receiver2_conv)
    act_receiver2=LeakyReLU()(receiver2_batch_norm)

    ## last set of CONV => BN=> RELU => RESID=> POOL => DROPOUT layers
    first_conv3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(act_receiver2)
    first_batch_norm3=BatchNormalization()(first_conv3)
    first_act3= LeakyReLU()(first_batch_norm3)

    second_conv3 = Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same")(act_receiver2)
    second_batch_norm3=BatchNormalization()(second_conv3)
    second_act3= LeakyReLU()(second_batch_norm3)

    third_conv3 = Conv2D(32, (7, 7), padding="same")(act_receiver2)
    third_batch_norm3=BatchNormalization()(third_conv3)
    third_act3= LeakyReLU()(third_batch_norm3)
        
    residual_block3= Add()([first_act3, second_act3, third_act3])
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(residual_block3)
    dropout3 = Dropout(0.3)(pool3)
    
    #last receiver Convolutional layer
    receiver3_conv = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(dropout3)
    receiver3_batch_norm=BatchNormalization()(receiver3_conv)
    act_receiver3=LeakyReLU()(receiver3_batch_norm)

    # prepare the final outputs
    pooledOutput = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(act_receiver3)
    outputs = Dense(embeddingDim)(pooledOutput)
    # build the model
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return(model)
```

However, this part **is connected to the input and output of my network** as a functional API. Here is how I link these parts:

```
print("[INFO] building siamese network...")
imgA = Input(shape=config.IMG_SHAPE)
imgB = Input(shape=config.IMG_SHAPE)

featureExtractor = build_siamese_model(config.IMG_SHAPE)

featsA = featureExtractor(imgA)
featsB = featureExtractor(imgB)

distance = Lambda(utils.euclidean_distance)([featsA, featsB])

outputs = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)
model = Model(inputs=[imgA, imgB], outputs=outputs)
```

However, when the model is compiled, here is the summary of the model:

[image]

**It seems therefore that my network definition done above is seen as just one layer of the network.**

**So, what do I want?**

I would like to load the model and extract the output of a specific layer. In special, I would like the output **of the last layer of the functional object (outputs = Dense(48)(pooledOutput) in the network definition above)**. This will give me a 48 feature vector for each pair of images I test in the model with.

I tried to check some [Previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950094/how-to-get-output-of-intermediate-keras-layers-in-batches) and did the following:

```
print("Step 1: Loading Model")

model1=load_model("where/the/model/is/located", compile=False)

#I tried the output of the firstlayer, for example
model_with_intermediate_layers = Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs = model1.layers[0].output)

pred = model_with_intermediate_layers.predict([pair_1,pair_2], steps = 1) 
print(pred)
```

**What is the problem??**

The problem with the code above is the fact that it only can access layers from 0, 1, 3 and 4. 0 and 1 give the input shapes, layer 3 gives me the score, and layer 4 is empty. **I would like to have access to an intermediate layer, especially the last layer of the feature extractor network. ** How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that (i) my Functional object is the second layer of the network; (ii) I want its final layer output; and (iii) the second layer output is the third layer's input, I solved the problem with the following code:

```
#I am getting layer's 3 input, which is the same as the second layer's output (last layer of my functional model)
model_intermediate = Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs = model1.layers[3].input)

#Here I get 2 48-d vectors.
pred_intermediate = model_intermediate.predict([pair_1,pair_2], steps = 1) # predict_generator is deprecated

pred_intermediate=np.array(pred_intermediate)

print(type(pred_intermediate))
print(pred_intermediate)
print(pred_intermediate.shape)
input()
```

which gives me what I want

[image]